How to add error handling to Python script for pyodbc error 40001?
I have below Python script that updates a record in the database.
connectionString = f'DRIVER={{ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server}};SERVER={SERVER};DATABASE={DATABASE};UID={USERNAME};PWD={PASSWORD}'
conn = pyodbc.connect(connectionString)
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute(f'UPDATE MYTABLE SET LastName = 'TestLName', FirstName = 'TestFName' WHERE ID = 1')
conn.commit()
conn.close()

Sometimes, I encounter the following error.
pyodbc.Error: ('40001', '[40001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Transaction (Process ID 97) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction. (1205) (SQLExecDirectW)')

How can I add error handling to the script so that it will retry updating the database if an error occurs?

try:
import pyodbc
import time

def update_database(conn):
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    try:
        cursor.execute(f"UPDATE MYTABLE SET LastName = 'TestLName', FirstName = 'TestFName' WHERE ID = 1")
        conn.commit()
    except pyodbc.Error as ex:
        sqlstate = ex.args[0]
        if sqlstate == '40001':  # Deadlock error
            print("Deadlock detected. Retrying...")
            time.sleep(1)  # Add a delay to avoid immediate retries
            update_database(conn)  # Retry the update with the same connection
        else:
            # Handle other exceptions
            print("Error:", ex)

# Create the connection outside the function
connectionString = f'DRIVER={{ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server}};SERVER={SERVER};DATABASE={DATABASE};UID={USERNAME};PWD={PASSWORD}'
conn = pyodbc.connect(connectionString)

# Call the function with the existing connection
update_database(conn)

# Close the connection after use
conn.close()


Should the connection be extracted as a parameter rather than recreated by recursion?
